# How to place a content on a css switch

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem to place a content on a css switch

Here is my code

```css
/* Css */

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<!-- Html: -->

<label class="switch"></label>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div class="slider round"></div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`adjacent sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and [`:checked selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). Example:

```css
div:before {
    content: "";
}

input:checked + div:before{
  content: 'foo';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<div></div>
```

[JSFiddle of your situation](https://jsfiddle.net/fvt64c7f/)